# Generate User Mock data dynamically

Tags: angular

I am working in Angular and while writing test cases I need mock data. I want to use a method which will give me desired data in the format which I want to use, let's say for example I have an interface of User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you can randomly generate the Mock Users using Math.Random() function.

Please have a look at the below URL, I have made a Example on StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpdery

Let me know in case you have any issues.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  IUser:any []= [{ id : 0, name : ''}]
```

// Suppose this is your USER Interface

```
  ngOnInit(){
    var temp :any [] = this.genrateUsers(10)
    temp.forEach(element =>{
      console.log('Element is',element)
    })
  }
```

// This function generates the Users randomly based on value of i passed as parameter to this function and return array of Users

```
  genrateUsers(i){
    this.IUser.length=0;
    for(var x=0; x<i; x++){
      this.IUser.push({id:Math.random().toString().substr(16),name:Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)})
    }
    return this.IUser
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [json-generator ("next" version)](https://next.json-generator.com/) when generating mock data for front end projects (This way, I don't need to wait for backend to be completed before starting on frontend, I only need the tentative data structure that is returned). It is created by Vazha Omanashvili, so all credits to him. This json-generator is built with JavaScript, therefore, allows JS code to be used also (i.e. Array methods, etc) which is perfect for front end developers. Basically, it provides a simple GUI with many built-in functions that allows you to quickly generate mock data in `.json` without having to spend a lot of time writing it out using raw javascript loops, etc.

For simpler mock data like your User Model it can be as simple as this, if you want more properties, you can add more code to the generating code:

**Simple mock data, generating code**:

```
[
  {
    'repeat(5, 10)': {
      id: '{{index()}}',
      name(tags) {
        return `Test-User-${this.id}`;
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test-User-0"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test-User-1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test-User-2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test-User-3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Test-User-4"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Test-User-5"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Test-User-6"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Test-User-7"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Test-User-8"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Test-User-9"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Test-User-10"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Test-User-11"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Test-User-12"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Test-User-13"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Test-User-14"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Test-User-15"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Test-User-16"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Test-User-17"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Test-User-18"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "name": "Test-User-19"
  }
]
```

For more complex data structure, you can link 2 arrays together, much like joining 2 db tables together.

**Complex mock data generating code - JavaScript + json-generator's built-in functions**

```
[
  {
    'repeat(5)':{
        category_id: "{{index()}}", //built-in function to generate IDsssssssss
        category_info(tags){
          const CATEGORIES = ['Dairy', 'Vegetables', 'Chips & Snacks'];

          const CATEGORY_DESCRIP = ['Products containing milk', 'Green and healthy', 'Unhealthy food'];

          let _oneRandCategory = CATEGORIES[tags.integer(0, CATEGORIES.length-1)]; //tags.integer is basically a built-in random integer method

          let _oneLinkedCatDescrip = CATEGORY_DESCRIP[CATEGORIES.indexOf(_oneRandCategory)]; //join by index of array

          return {category:_oneRandCategory , description:_oneLinkedCatDescrip };
        }
    }
  }
]
```

**Generated results, json format**

```
[
  {
    "category_id": 0,
    "category_info": {
      "category": "Vegetables",
      "description": "Green and healthy"
    }
  },
  {
    "category_id": 1,
    "category_info": {
      "category": "Dairy",
      "description": "Products containing milk"
    }
  },
  {
    "category_id": 2,
    "category_info": {
      "category": "Dairy",
      "description": "Products containing milk"
    }
  },
  {
    "category_id": 3,
    "category_info": {
      "category": "Dairy",
      "description": "Products containing milk"
    }
  },
  {
    "category_id": 4,
    "category_info": {
      "category": "Chips & Snacks",
      "description": "Unhealthy food"
    }
  }
]
```

As you may observe, category and description are "joined" together via the array's index - like 2 db tables joined together. So the 2 arrays in the generating code acts as mock db tables. I can simply change `repeat(5)` to `repeat(100)` and generate 100x objects to test look and feel of pagination in frontend table or search/filter functions, etc.

---

After generating the mock data, you have to save the json array in a `.json` file or just add it in to your test case/component as an array. I prefer to put it in a separate folder so I may reuse in different places e.g. `app/mockdata/mock-users-data.json`.

Then, import the json file with `import { users } from 'app/mockdata/mock-users-data.json`. `users` is an arbitrary identifier, you can name it whatever you want to identify the json array in the json file. Then use `users` in your code, e.g. `let mockUsers = users`.

Answer (score 0):

If You want some kind of server to call and get test data you can use : [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

JSONPlaceholder is a free online REST API that you can use whenever you need some fake data.
It's great for tutorials, testing new libraries, sharing code examples, ...

Even You can create your own test data: [My JSON Server :Fake Online REST server for teams](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/)

**How to**

Create a repository on GitHub (/)
Create a db.json file
Visit https://my-json-server.typicode.com// to access your server
No registration. Nothing to install.